# How do I sort this Dictionary of Dictionaries of Lists of Lists of ints by value?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

Hello I have a little problem sorting this dictionary by the int values.

This is Dictionary:

```
_cleanHelper = 
    new Dictionary<Direction, Dictionary<CleanTypes, List<List<int>>>>()
{
    {
        Direction.North, new Dictionary<CleanTypes, List<List<int>>>()
        {
            {
                CleanTypes.Walled, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, -1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, -1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, 0
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, 1
                    }, 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 1
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Close, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Recurse, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        Direction.South, new Dictionary<CleanTypes, List<List<int>>>()
        {
            {
                CleanTypes.Walled, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, -1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, -1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, 0
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, 1
                    }, 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 1
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Close, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Recurse, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        Direction.West, new Dictionary<CleanTypes, List<List<int>>>()
        {
            {
                CleanTypes.Walled, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, 0
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, 1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, 1
                    }, 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Close, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Recurse, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, -1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        Direction.East, new Dictionary<CleanTypes, List<List<int>>>()
        {
            {
                CleanTypes.Walled, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, 0
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        -1, -1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, -1
                    },
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, -1
                    }, 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        1, 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Close, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                CleanTypes.Recurse, new List<List<int>>()
                { 
                    new List<int>()
                    {
                        0, 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

At Runtime I make several copies of this and need to have a way to sort them by the integer values in ascending order. How would I best do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: A Dictionary of Dictionaries of Lists of Lists of ints? Mother of god. Couldn't you clean this up a bit with some kind of `Vector` or `Point` data type?

Comment: A redesign of your data structure would probably be advisable...

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to change the contained values. That means this is probably what you're after:

```
foreach (var item in _cleanHelper)
{
    foreach (var jtem in item.Value)
    {
        jtem.Value.Sort((a, b) =>
        {
            int cmp = a[0].CompareTo(b[0]);
            return (cmp == 0) ? a[1].CompareTo(b[1]) : cmp;
        });
    }
}
```

That said, I'd never implement it like this... I'd probably create a 'Point' class for the coordinates, and looking at the keys you use for the dictionaries I'd probably implement them as a single 'Direction' class or something similar. That will probably make your code much more readable and as a bonus makes the structure easier to traverse with f.ex. Linq.